# multiple url restrictions in google custom search

Tags: google-custom-search

Hi I have set up a paid google custom search for my domain.
Is there a way to limit the results based on the directory that the search is currently in?

The directories that I need to limit the search to are company divisional sites, so should only show results based on that divisional directory

For example:

In http://www.mysite.com/* shows the results that appear in the site

In http://www.mysite.com/directory1/* the results that appear in directory1

In http://www.mysite.com/directory2/* shows the results that appear in directory2

etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can limit the results to a domain using:

```
&as_sitesearch=mydomain.com
```

so, using this technique, you can limit your results to a folder in a domain. For example:

```
http://www.google.com/cse?cx=YOUR-GOOGLE-ID&client=google-csbe&output=xml_no_dtd&filter=1&q=post&num=10&start=10&&as_sitesearch=YOUR-DOMAIN.com/send-uk
```

The previous url will only display the links in yourdomain that are inside SEND-UK. Just tested and it works fine :-).

You can see this example working in this Drupal module, where I am using exactly this idea, even I did not know that you could limit also by folder: